# Existence of a linear structure in a space of homomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism, continuous-homomorphisms

Let $H$ be an (uncountable) set of homomorphisms from an additive group $\Gamma$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Is it possible to define a linear structure on $H$ (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$)? In case it is not always possible how can one prove that given $H$ cannot become linear no matter how the actions of addition and multiplication by scalars are defined?

Comment: Do you require any compatibility of the structure with the homomorphisms themselves? If not, then if $H$ has the same cardinality as the reals, one can simply pick any bijection $H \leftrightarrow \Bbb R$ and use it to define a linear structure on $H$ by declaring the bijection to be an isomorphism.

Comment: If we're allowed to add homomorphisms to $H$ (in order to get its "span"), then presumably we could define
$$
[a \phi + b \psi] (x) = a \cdot \phi(x) + b \cdot \psi(x)
$$
for $a,b \in \Bbb C$, $\phi, \psi \in H$ and $x \in \Gamma$.

Comment: If all you care about is *if* any addition and scalar multiplication operations can be defined, "no matter how," then it seems you only care about this set of maps as a set with no regards for what form the elements actually take. *Any* uncountable set can be made a vector space over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ whilst completely ignoring what the elements of the set are. (This is basically Travis' comment.) @Omnomnomnom As I understand the situation, OP's set $H$ may not be closed under addition or scalar multiplication - for instance it might not have the zero map.

Comment: In fact $H$ has a zero element i.e. the homomorphism which assigns 0 to each element of $\Gamma$. The problem is to define the sum $h+g$ of two homomorphisms $h,g\in H$ in the most sensible way, since the mapping obtained from pointwise summation which is the most natural candidate for $h+g$ is not a homomorphism.